# Passing format specifier to printf in macro

Tags: c, macros, format-specifiers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define PRINT(A,B) printf("Value of expression %s is %*",#A,#B,(A))
int main(void){
    PRINT(1+3+1,%d);
    return 0;
}
```

How to write a macro which gets **two arguments**: `expression` and `format specifier` then printing expression and value of it in given format?

Comment: Why are you using macro to do this? Makes code difficult to read

Answer (score 6):

`%d` is a format *string*, so it needs to be in double quotes, like any other string literal. Also, use meaningful names for identifiers.

```
#define PRINT(expr, fmt) printf("Value of expression %s is " fmt "\n", #expr, expr)

PRINT(1+3+1, "%d");
```

You can get away with the preprocessor's stringification operator to turn something like `%d` into `"%d"`, but it's fragile (it's very sensitive to whitespace), risk-prone (code analysis tools that don't run a preprocessor may think that the code is using the variable `d` or choke on a syntax error on `%` with no left-hand side), and most importantly, it's misleading for human readers.

As a rule of thumb, you should only use unhygienic macros (macros that depart from the syntax of the language) if you have a very good reason. Typesetting an expression for debugging purposes (`#expr`) is a good reason. Writing programs that are two characters shorter is a good reason only if you're entering an obfuscated programming contest.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
#define PRINT(A,B) printf("Value of expression %s is "#B"\n",#A,(A))
```